# How do spam users register while I've only enabled registration by Gmail via Janrain?

Tags: user-registration, spam

In [wp-login.php?action=register](http://gakuiryugaku.net/wp-login.php?action=register), I've disabled text fields (sorry this web site is in Japanese only but hope you can see that there's no text field) and enabled registration only via [social login by janrain plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/), and set it to accept `GMail` only. In this way I expect all new users have `GMail` addresses.

However there are still new users who aren't using `GMail`, and what's worse is they look like spam. Examples are:

```
Account name: Anddcusd, cqbx33@groupd-mail.net
Account name: Anddcuse, cqbx34@groupd-mail.net
Account name: Anddcusg, cqbx36@groupd-mail.net
```

How can they still create accounts, with non-approved email addresses? Thanks!

`WP` 3.5, `Janrain Engage` 1.1.1

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, under Settings -> General you do have anyone can register unchecked right?  A bot can submit the registration form text fields or no.  Have you contacted the plugin author?

Comment: @Andrew Bartel No I don't uncheck it, since I want anyone to create an account as long as they are logged on to GMail (I actually made sure how unchecking it works, and yes it forbids creation of new user even with GMail).

Comment: So, because that is checked, someone or a program can manually submit a post and achieve a registration, it doesn't necessarily have to be through the web form.  As I asked before, have you contacted the plugin author about this?  You could write a script to remove users that don't have a gmail address too.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution to block spam users register or comments is http://wordpress.org/plugins/cookies-for-comments/

Comment: Please explain why do you think this is solution to this problem and why it's the best solution.